# What are $L_1$ and $L_2$ in the Gödel Constructible Hierarchy

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I'll start by defining the constructible hierarchy for the sake of proper prefacing to the question. So we begin by defining:

$$
\operatorname{Def}(X) := \big\{ \{ y\mid y \in X \text{ and } (X,\in) \vDash \Phi(y, z_1, \ldots , z_n) \; \} \;\big|\;  \Phi \text { is a first order formula and } z_1, \ldots, z_n \in X \big\}.
$$

The Gödel Constructible Hierarchy then follows with transfinite recursion as:

$$
L_0 := \emptyset \\
L_{\alpha + 1} := \operatorname{Def}(L_\alpha).
$$

Or if, $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal, then we can define:

$$
L_\lambda := \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} L_\alpha.
$$

---

*Note.* This is not for school, I'm just reading Paul Cohen's book on the Continuum Hypothesis for funzies.

My question is: what is $L_1$ and $L_2$ in the hierarchy? Based on my working things out, it seems to me that:

$$
L_1 := \{\emptyset\}, \text{ and } \\
L_2 := \big\{\{\emptyset\}\big\}.
$$

But, I feel like that may be incorrect. And, given that the last time I was looking over the material was 10 years ago, I figured that I'd ask the community.

Comment: That's correct. For $n$ finite, $L_{n+1}$ is just the power set of $L_n$, so $L_n=V_n$.

Comment: You missed a definable subset of $L_1$ for $L_2$ !

Comment: Ok. Power set makes sense as well. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a slightly more general way to approach this issue.

> If $X$ is a finite set such that every element of $X$ is definable, then $\operatorname{Def}(X)=\mathcal P(X)$.

This is not very hard, but now we combine this with the following observation:

> If $X$ is a finite transitive set, then every member of $X$ is definable.

To see why, we can prove this by recursion on the rank of the members of $X$: if $x$ is such that all the members of $x$ are definable, then $x$ is the unique set such that $y\in\leftrightarrow\bigvee_{u\in x}\varphi_u(y)$, where $\varphi_u$ is a formula defining $u$.

---

Now we get the full power of the construction, up to $\omega$:

1. $L_0=\varnothing$, certainly a finite transitive set;
2. $L_{n+1}=\operatorname{Def}(L_n)$, but since $L_n$ is finite and transitive, this is just $\mathcal P(L_n)$, and in particular a transitive finite set.

So indeed, $L_1=\{\varnothing\}$ and $L_2=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$.

Comment: I am not sure I follow the argument. If $x\subseteq X$ and each $u\in X$ is definable, this means that there are formulas $\varphi_u$, $u\in X$, that *in $V$*, define these sets. But you then need to argue that the $\varphi_u$ (or some suitable modification) define $u$ *in $X$*, so that you can then use them to define $x$ *in $X$*.

Comment: If $\varphi_u$ defines $u$, then $x=\{y\in X\mid\bigvee_{u\in X}\varphi_u(y)\}$.

Comment: Yes, but this is not enough. As written, you only know that $\varphi_u$ defines $u$ in $V$. What you need instead is that $x=\{y\in X\mid (X,\in)\models\bigvee_{u\in x}\varphi_u(y)\}$, and I don't see from what you have said how to conclude that this is the case.

Comment: I have two unrelated facts. The first is that for a transitive finite sets, all the members are definable; the second is that for a finite set with every member definable, the definable power set is the power set. That we may need to change the definitions is immaterial here, I think.

Comment: I thought you were proving your first claim, or a combination of both claims together, and I didn't see how your argument worked. I see from your comment that you are not, you are just indicating how, using the claims as black boxes, the result follows.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I gave an explanation below the second claim why this claim is true (one could argue it's a semi-proof). But the idea is to use these two as blackboxes for the general result.

Answer (score 2):

As Wojowu said above, for any arbitrar $n\in\mathbb{N}$, 
$$
\text{Def}(L_n) = \mathcal{P}(L_n),
$$
where $\mathcal{P}(X)$ represents the power set of $X$. So,

$$
L_1 := \{\emptyset\} \\
L_2 := \left\{ \emptyset, \{\emptyset\} \right\}
$$